# Setting up icinga2 to allow API access

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, api, nagios

I'm looking to access the monitoring data in `icinga2` via a RESTful API, from another server.

I've got these package versions installed on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`:

```
icinga2            2.3.11-1~ppa1~trusty1
icinga2-common     2.3.11-1~ppa1~trusty1
icinga2-ido-mysql  2.3.11-1~ppa1~trusty1
icinga2-classicui  2.3.11-1~ppa1~trusty1
icingaweb2         2.0.0-1~ppa1
```

Apache is currently set up to use the `classicui`, which might be part of my problem..?

I have seen and read the [WIKI page](https://wiki.icinga.org/display/Dev/Icinga-Web+REST+API) for the Icinga-Web REST API, but it refers to files I don't see *anywhere** in my installation (`icinga-web/app/modules/AppKit/config/auth.xml`) and that wiki page was last updated in 2012.

I'm getting the feeling that it may be way out of date and there is no REST API any more?

Would appreciate any links to current information or any tutorials on getting the API access working. Thanks! :)

*I tried to tag this question with `icinga` but don't have enough rep to create a new tag, so had to use `nagios` instead.*

---

* - by 'anywhere', I mean a `find / -name 'auth.xml'` fails to locate any files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API is not included in any icinga2 release. The REST API will be included in the next major version. There Wiki page you are referring to is for Icingaweb, which is the old Webfrontend. Icingaweb2 doesn't have a full REST Api by now. If you want to try the new API, you can use a snapshot build from packages.icinga.org.